# Photos app - moving pictures and re-associating

Tags: macos, photos, photos.app

I have been organizing years of photos and photo albums into Apple's new Photos app. I recently picked up a new SSD to just handle my photo collection. I moved all of the photos to that drive. Now the file association in my Photos library is wrong for every photo. Is there a clean way to update all?

I've tried manually associating a few images, but that only takes care of that album. I have hundreds of albums.

It would be great if I could just find all references to the old path via SQL statement and replace. I'm sure it's not that simple though.

Any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: couldn't you just make a symbolic link from the Photos library to its old location?

Comment: find any photo, right click/get info, set Open with: to Photos, then just underneath, Change All...

Comment: Do you use a referenced library? Photos menu > Preferences > General > if the box next to "Import" is _unchecked_, you have a referenced library.

Comment: It's a referenced library. I didn't want to import all of the photos into the app since that would just duplicate everything on my drive. I like to store the photos in once place..

Comment: You can still have your Library on an external drive, referenced or not. Just launch with opt held & it will ask for a Lib location or make new Lib